# Alfresco Activiti or Camunda or jBPM - Associating a task to an external URL

Tags: activiti, business-process-management, camunda

Is it possible to associate a process task (in Alfresco Activiti or Camunda) to an external URL to open a form produced by an external web application?

I am using the current versions of these products for prototyping:

- **Alfresco-Process-Services 1.8.1**
- ** Activiti 6.0.0**
- **Camunda 7.8.0**
- **jBPM 7.1.0.Final**

The idea is to use the native UI (equivalent to KIE Workbench in jBPM 7.1.0.Final), to create the process definition and associate one of its user tasks to an external URL (kind of redirection or inside a pop up) where the user claiming this task (after publishing and starting the process instance) will be redirected to the external web app to complete the task as the logic is contained in our external web app.

Comment: Are you using the native UI or rolling your own ? Also, can you be more specific about the Activiti/Camunda version you're using ?

Comment: I am using the current versions of both products for prototyping:

**Alfresco-Process-Services 1.8.1 or Activiti 6.0.0**
**Camunda 7.8.0**
**jBPM 7.1.0.Final**
 The idea is to use the native UI (equivalent to KIE Workbench in jBPM 7.1.0.Final), to create the process definition and associate one of its user tasks to an external URL (kind of redirection or inside a pop up) where the user claiming this task (after publishing and starting the process instance) will be redirected to the external web app to complete the task as the logic is contained in our external web app.

Answer (score 3):

In Camunda you can use External Forms to jump to some arbitrary URL (some parameters are added to URL to identity the task and callback URL for example), see https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/user-guide/task-forms/#external-task-forms

Answer (score 2):

In Activiti 6 and Alfresco Process Services, the legacy "Form key" property is still retained which is an arbitrary metadata key that can be  used to identify the key to an external form.

This key is still exposed in the Activiti 6 and APS process editors.

Keep in mind, the APS (and Activiti 6) form editor overloads the form key field with the referenced form ID, so if you use it you cannot use the built-in forms.

Hope this helps,
Greg